# Hide all elements with a specific class and show by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have all elements of a specific class being hidden upon page load using jquery's `hide()` function. I am trying to display the element again based upon it's ID when a link is clicked.

There are 7 elements with the class being hidden, each with a different ID. When the link containing `href="#element-id"` is clicked it should show only that element and keep all other elements hidden.

Here is my current code hiding the elements:

```
var menu = $('div.menu-wrapper');
menu.hide();
```

And here is what I have that is supposed to display the correct element on click:

```
$('area').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') !== 'button') {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        target.toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 900);    
    }
});
```

Right now nothing happens when clicking on the element. How can I keep all elements with the class `menu-wrapper` hidden while only the element with the class `menu-wrapper` and the correct ID is visible?

Comment: can we also see the html? or at least a pattern of how it is

Comment: as far as I can see you are trying to show the <a> attribute 'href' instead of the anchor itself, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: $('area') is not a valid selector missing a dot or a #

Comment: `$('area')` is a valid selector. It is used in Image Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var menu = $('div.menu-wrapper');
menu.hide();
//register the event handler to area elements other than #button
$('a:not(#button)').click(function () {
    //hide all elements referred menu
    menu.hide();
    //get the target jQuery wrapper, the href need to start with #
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    target.toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
    }, 900);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I need. Will accept answer as soon as I am able. -- One issue is that it now doesn't slide out, but simply just appears. It slides back in fine though... Any solution for this?